BlenderBim and BlenderDocumentation does not show in sidebar
Im completely new when it comes to blender, but I try to learn it with some tutorials. I installed BlenderBim and it partially works. But it doesnt show "BlenderBim" and "BIMDocumentation" on a sidebar. I tried to switch off other add-ons, re-install it, but nothing works. This is the view I have. Is there anything I can do about it? 

Go to the topbar and do Window > Toggle System Console to enable the Python console. The go into the addons panel and uncheck then recheck the addons and watch what happens in the system console. You'll probably see a bunch of text flying by, scan over that and see if anything says something like Traceback (most recent call last)... and see if any of the filepaths the error is related to are from that addon. If you see that can you post the error text here?

That's a third-party addon so you should really ask questions about it on its web page. There's a YT video about it here with links to a community page below it.. It's also worth checking that you have a version installed that is compatible with the version of Blender that you are using. - For instance it's very unlikely that a version which seems to have been last updated in 2023 will work in Blender 4.2!

Hello, please go there for issues regarding the (now called) Bonsai addon. https://github.com/IfcOpenShell/IfcOpenShell/issues Blenderkit is know for conflicting with the addon, please try to disable it.

You may need to switch to the BIM workspace from the top tabs. Also object properties only show if you select something in the 3D View

Indeed, not only the addon changed name to Bonsai, but it doesn't seem fully released for 4.2 yet. At least the migration to the new extension is ongoing, and though it is available on the extension platform, it is still marked as an alpha version. So if I were you, I would either use the latest possible version from the extensions platform, or install the legacy addon with the procedure advised here.
